# What can you do with dolphins?

Tags: minecraft-legacy-console

In Minecraft, there are dolphins. Can you tame them? I am playing on the Xbox 360 version.

Answer (score 2):

Dolphins in Minecraft are not rideable. However, there is an achievement on the Xbox 360 version of the game that is associated with them:

> **Echolocation**: Feed a dolphin fish and have it lure you to treasure.

Only one fish is needed to feed the dolphin for the achievement, but it must specifically be raw fish and not cooked fish - I can confirm that raw cod works, and I believe that raw salmon does too.

(From the Minecraft wiki's [page on dolphins.](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Dolphin))

Comment: How many fish do you need?

Comment: @SliverMoon I've added detail to my answer.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to Lamprey's answer, when swimming near dolphins, they can boost your swimming speed greatly. This will happen automatically simply by swimming near them

Answer (score 0):

Building on Ben's answer. There is the possibility of capturing dolphins and holding them in little tanks in the ocean spread about 80 block from one another. If you have multiple dolphins captured that way you can make kind of a underwater highway of sorts.

Swimming has never been that fun before.